# How to send request body in post curl

Tags: curl

I have written an API in java. Trying to hit using curl from the shell script.

```
local CONTENT_SOURCE="$1"

curl "$APP_URL/api/admin/sync" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"content": "$CONTENT_SOURCE", "usernames": ["abcuser@gmail.com"]}' \
  -w "\n"
```

How to send CONTENT_SOURCE in the request body?

Answer (score 1):

Build your JSON data with `jq` like this:

```sh
JSON_DATA=$(jq --null-input --arg content "${CONTENT_SOURCE}" '{"content": $content, "usernames": ["abcuser@gmail.com"]}')
```

And use it with your cURL command:

```sh
curl "$APP_URL/api/admin/sync" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data "${JSON_DATA}" \
  -w "\n"
```

Comment: content is coming as `$content`

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the quotes around `${content}` in `jq` command